# How do I get Android to ask the user if they would like to use my app as the Launcher?

Tags: android, launcher

I'm adding

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

to my activity's definition in the manifest, but now the home button just pops open my app by default.  I'd like it to ask the user if they'd like to use my Launcher or the stock one. What do I need to add to the manifest to make sure they get that choice?

Here's an example of someone else doing this...
http://blog.mycolorscreen.com/post/9328914812/customizing-your-android-without-rooting

they offer a Home switcher when someone hits the Home button. I'm not finding any documentation on what this entails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens automatically. When your app is installed, the next time the user presses HOME, they will get a chooser, asking whether the user wants your app or another home screen already installed. They will continue to get this chooser until such time as they click the "make this the default" checkbox and make one final choice, after which they will get their chosen activity on future HOME presses.

My guess is that, somewhere along the line, you checked that checkbox on the chooser. You can clear it from being the default via the Settings app, or simply uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: that's what I was expecting as well, and maybe I'm not getting that choice because I'm installing straight from eclipse? But in both Honeycomb and Gingerbread after I install my app (having made no choices of any kind) the Home button auto defaults to my app and bypasses the home screen completely (which, in Gingerbread actually creates the possibility of my app being total malware, since if I run it full screen, it would make it literally impossible for the user to ever get out of it or exit it!)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: "maybe I'm not getting that choice because I'm installing straight from eclipse?" -- conceivably, though I'm not aware of that being the case. You could always test the theory by exporting an APK from Eclipse and installing that by some other means (e.g., install from a DropBox folder).

Comment: To add insult to injury, I just totally locked myself out of my phone by rebooting it! If I didn't have access to adb this would be a total disaster!

Comment: yeah, I just did a normal adb install, as well as an over the air install... none of these make a difference. The end result is the same... quite unintentionally, my app is 100% malware at the moment!

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: With respect to locking yourself out of your phone, you could always reboot in safe mode. Are these normal devices, or are they unusual (modded ROMs, off-brand, etc.)? Also, you might want to try the Home sample in the SDK to see if it gives you equivalent behavior.

Comment: yeah, totally native RAZR MAXX running 2.3.6. Nothing custom at all.  Sure, I can reboot in Safe mode, but talk about a hassle! I'm tempted to pust my entire code, since there's really pretty much nothing in it (it's one activity and a manifest). I'm actually working off of the Home sample, and that's what brought me here to begin with. I was expecting the behavior you initially described (with the dialog asking the user what they want to use) but for some reason am not seeing it.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: You might try the MOTODEV support boards, then.

Comment: You can use ADB to uninstall your app. This should restore the default Launcher.

Comment: @Lawrence, yes, I understand that, my confusion isn't in how to deal with the app; my confusion is why it's not offering the end user a prompt as to what launcher they would like to use.